# How to solve Dependent Errors in Multivariate linear regressions in R?

Tags: r, regression

I am doing a multi-regression with the code below. As the observations were picked by year, I found the error were not independent when I checked the assumptions. Is there anyway to correct the code by R? Thank you!

```
mod.fit<-lm(formula = NDMNE ~ DEGUSNE + DURUSNE, data = reg)
summary(mod.fit)
```

Data is as below:

```
Year    NDMNE   DEGUSNE DURUSNE
1999    -4627   -0.016  -2
2001    -7718   -0.012  -1.167
2002    -5287   0.003   -1.6
2003    -1319   0.014   -2.05
2004    -5182   0.016   -1.992
2005    -3286   -0.004  -1.608
2006    -5578   -0.019  -1.233
2007    -4869   -0.018  -1.558
2008    -1491   -0.002  -1.658
2009    -956    0.018   -2.5
2011    -1100   0.002   -4.483
2012    -967    -0.002  -4.058
2013    -695    -0.011  -3.475
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not the code that is wrong, but rather the model assumptions. This is a statistical question off-topic in SO. Go to CrossValidated.com. You should edit the question to show how you determined that "the error were not independent".

Comment: Thanks @BondedDust, maybe I didn't express correctly, but is there any way I can do with the dependent error? Like any transformation to the variable?

Comment: There are many methods to model nonlinear relationships between predictors and outcomes. Regressions splines are well supported in R. But again, this is a stistical problem where you are asking for advice and you've already been given clear direction on where to go.